# Using JaCoCo with Liberty Profile 8.5.5.4 in Eclipse does not produce any code coverage

Tags: eclipse, jacoco, websphere-liberty

I am trying to use JaCoCo for code coverage. I am running Liberty from Eclipse (using the Eclipse launcher). In jvm.options, I added these lines: (substitute <location> for a path)

```
-Xshareclasses:none
-javaagent:<location>/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=jacoco.exec,output=file,append=false,classdumpdir=./classdump
```

however, after running the tests, I do not see any coverage information. It looks like JaCoCo cannot link to the Java classes that are in my web application war file.

Is there a different process run by liberty that has the java classes? Can a java agent be attached to that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using JaCoCo 0.7.3 or later?  If yes, I suspect the problem is caused by changes in [issue #272](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/272) because last I checked, WebSphere Liberty profile did not define classes with a CodeSource location, so this heuristic in JaCoCo causes all classes in applications running on WebSphere Liberty profile to be ignored.  If you can confirm that's the case for your application on some recent Liberty fixpak (`MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`), then I would suggest opening a [WebSphere RFE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181), a [JaCoCo issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues), or both.

Comment: Yes, I am using JaCoCo 0.7.6. I didn't understand what you meant by " some recent Liberty fixpak (MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation())", could you please elaborate?
I also tried to use offline instrumentation, but had no luck there either (no jacoco.exec was being generated).

Comment: You can download the latest beta from http://wasdev.net/.  You should add that snippet of code to some class in your application (e.g., a servlet) to see if it's returning null; if it is null, then JaCoCo 0.7.3+ won't work.  That said, if you can't get offline instrumentation to work, then I'm really not sure; as soon as an offline-instrumented class is used, it should cause the JaCoCo runtime to write at least an empty jacoco.exec file (with all defaults, it would go to the same directory as server.xml).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the null check thing, I'll give that a try. Regarding the offline instrumentation, I have probably misplaced some parameter or something related to JVM classpath (don't think WAS allows JVM classpath to be modified, and I don't know how to resolve that). WAS could load the instrumented classes without error, which is giving me hope :)

Comment: If JaCoCo was not somehow on the classpath, I'm not sure how any of the offline-instrumented classes would load.  You should be able to use -javaagent even with offline instrumentation; that will add the JaCoCo JAR to the JVM classpath and eagerly create the jacoco.exec file during JVM startup even though it (probably) won't instrument anything due to the code source location issue.

Comment: For the offline instrumented servlet classes, I placed the jacoco.jar inside my application's WAR file, so I guess JaCoCo is in the classpath when my app is loaded by liberty. However, no jacoco.exec file was created. Do I have to supply any arguments to jvm.options or modify the server.xml?

Comment: I would have expected that to work too.  The offline-instrumented classes should cause the jacoco.exec file to be written as soon as they're used.  You might try running with -verbose:class to see if the JaCoCo classes are being loaded, but otherwise, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

Had to use an older version of JaCoCo (0.7.2) instead of the latest (0.7.6).

Thanks to [bkail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142446/bkail)

Comment: Please accept my answer if it solved the problem (click the green checkmark next to the answer).  I strongly recommend you to report this issue to at least JaCoCo if not IBM since you do not want to stay on an old version of JaCoCo indefinitely.